# Blackberry phonegap application not supported lower version?

Tags: html, cordova

I am new to blackberry phonegap application,i developed blackberry phonegap application its working fine in blackberry curve 8520 with version 5.0,but it's not working in lower version 4..0.
  Please help me...

Comment: It's general idea.. your lower version may run on higher version but it's difficult(Surely not possible) to run higher version on lower.

Comment: Say more about what is "not working"

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Blackberry):

> Cordova for BlackBerry makes use of the BlackBerry WebWorks framework.
>   BlackBerry WebWorks tooling is available for Windows or Mac
>   environments. **WebWorks applications can ONLY be deployed to BlackBerry
>   devices running OS 5.0 and higher or the BlackBerry PlayBook operating
>   system.**